# Bootstrap (radio) button group in multiple lines

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a button group of several items that have to behave as radio buttons. I also need them broken into several rows and spanning the entire width of the container.

To this end I used bootstrap's class `btn-group-justified`, and I split the `<input type="radio">` elements into several button groups, while keeping the same name.

This looks ok, but has the side effect of buttons not toggling checked elements in other groups, even though they have the same `name`. That is, **they stop behaving as radio buttons in the same group**.

**Jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/madariaga/brgoyb9d/3/).** As you can see, if you select a button on the first row and then click one on the second, the first element isn't toggled off.

Is there a way to get a multiple-line button group without hacking the radio behavior together with javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having this for the two groups `<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm btn-group-justified" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">`
just have it at the top, but without btn-group-justified.  Then for the two groups just do `<div class="btn-group-justified"> ... your buttons here ...</div>`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, doing that and additionally moving up `data-toggle` worked.

Comment: dear peers.. could you provide a working example? i am trying to archive the same thing without success.. thanks you very much!

Comment: i'm afraid is too late, i already address this matter in another way... the code was pretty much like the example Mariano gave in his post. I just wanted to have to in two different rows radio buttons that belongs to the same group. I was unable to archive it without having the css style broken. (I was able to achieve this, but the css style of the button was a mix of radio button and a button, so the visualization was bad)

Comment: Any idea how to do this with react-bootstrap? Tried combining ButtonGroups and ToggleButtonGroups - it does not work

Answer (score 6):

This did the trick.

http://www.bootply.com/k067OmtNXt

```
<div data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio"> Lorem
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio"> ipsum
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```